# Connect to guest vm (no wifi driver) from machines on same wireless network as the host machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge, nixos

I have my host os with proper wifi drivers that connects to my router. I run a NixOs VM (no wifi driver) as guest. I setup some configs in NixOS and it now has many binary caches that I want to share with machines on wireless network that host is part of - using nixos-serve. I couldn't get bridge networking to work in virtualbox.

VirtualBox gives me two interfaces : wlp7s0 and enp9s0

wlp7s0 is host machine's wireless interface.
enp9s0 is host machine's ethernet interface.

now How do I make guest to join the wireless network ?

can I make an ad-hoc connection between host and guest and hence let other machines on wireless network access guest's IP via host as gateway?

Comment: It is a virtual environment. Connect the ethernet interface in bridge mode to the real wireless interface, or if the local wireless/AP security does not allow it, setup it in Virtual Box as NAT.

Answer (score 0):

If bridged mode doesn't work due to it not being an open wi-fi access point then go with NAT and create a forwarding rule in the main virtualbox interface for the virtual machine